# Checkbox do not return the checked value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 checkboxes.

[image: this is my design view]

## my code behind:

```
int e_n_SG = 0;
int e_n_PR = 0;
int e_n_FG = 0;
if (natSG.Checked)
{
    e_n_SG = 1;
}
if (natPR.Checked)
{
    e_n_PR = 1;
}

if (natFG.Checked)
{
    e_n_FG = 1;
}

addScholarship updated1 = new addScholarship(agg, gender, criteria, id1, e_n_SG, e_n_PR, e_n_FG);

update1[0] = updated1;
```

when i check foreigner , it will return singaporean when i try to retrieve the data. and when  i check singaporean, it display nothing. i tried to debug and i noticed e_n_FG is not being retrieved. :

[image]

my constructor:

```
public addScholarship(int Aggregate, string Gender, string OtherDetails, int Scholarship_id, int e_n_SG, int e_n_PR, int e_n_FG)
{
    this.Aggregate = Aggregate;
    this.Gender = Gender;
    this.OtherDetails = OtherDetails;
    this.Scholarship_id = Scholarship_id;
    this.e_n_SG = e_n_SG;
    this.e_n_PR = e_n_PR;
    this.e_n_SG = e_n_FG;
}
```

anyone could advise me?

Comment: what addScholarship method do ? possibly you are missing mapping for that field

Comment: addscholarship is my constructor. i have added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public addScholarship(int Aggregate, string Gender, string OtherDetails, int Scholarship_id, int e_n_SG, int e_n_PR, int e_n_FG)
    {
        this.Aggregate = Aggregate;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.OtherDetails = OtherDetails;
        this.Scholarship_id = Scholarship_id;
        this.e_n_SG = e_n_SG;
        this.e_n_PR = e_n_PR;
        this.e_n_SG = e_n_FG; // <--- it should be this.e_n_FG = e_n_FG;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake.

Comment: There's probably a lesson there in making sure variables are named clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use in Control** 
Use AutoPostBack="true" with event

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```